# Copy Folders from one Unix server to another?

Tags: unix

I would like to copy a folder from one Unix server to another Unix server. Can anyone tell me if there is a method or command to to achieve this?

Answer (score 33):

Yes, there is [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) or the former [rcp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp) or [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

```
scp -r source_folder user@host.com:destination_folder
```

The command above will copy `source_folder` to `destination_folder` in the `user's` home directory on `host.com`

Comment: I haven't seen rcp for *decades* - does anyone still use that?

Comment: @Piskvor: I have never used it either, but was just added there for completeness of the answer.

Comment: if you want completeness, you should add the netcat method too. `nc -l -p 9999 > file` + `cat file | nc ip port`  or `nc -l -p 9999 | tar -x -` + `tar -c dir | nc ip port` - has saved my skin a couple of times when i didn't have any fancy servers available, like linux installer systems

Answer (score 14):

If your folder contains subfolders and more importantly symlinks you want to use *rsync*:

```
rsync -aruv localfolder/ user@server:destination/
```

Or in reverse:

```
rsync -aruv user@server:destination/ localfolder/
```

This will do a recursive backup / copy from localfolder to your server while keeping   ownership and permissions intact.
The solutions suggested so far are valid however scp doesn't handle symlinks by default and
will instead create a new copy of the linked file.

For detailed usage see **man(1) rsync** or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy):

```
scp -rp foldertocopy/ user@server:destination/
```

or

[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Answer (score 0):

First login to the server to which you want to copy folder or file.
Be in folder where u want to copy and 
execute command "wget http://sourceserverip/folderuwanttocopy.zip"

for this folderuwanttocpy.zip in source server should be in /var/www/html if it is linux server  (or) xamp/httdocs if it is windows server